# MigrateDbToLatestVersion does not work

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, database-migration

I am hoping someone can shed some light on this subject because so far it is a bit of a mystery and I have not been able to find an answer after searching around.

We have an app where we're using EF code first to do db migrations on existing databases. Our app uses 2 databases and we have 2 DALs where each has a separate DbContext for accessing its respective database. For simplicity's sake our solution looks as follows:

Solution

- DataAccessLayerA --> DatabaseA
- DataAccessLayerB --> DatabaseB

The problem we're seeing is that on DataAccessLayerA our MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer works great and our DatabaseA gets migrated.
However, on DataAccessLayerB the MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion initializer does absolutely nothing and our DatabaseB does not get migrated.

Here's the code we're executing on DataAccessLayerA:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ContextA,     DALA.Migrations.Configuration>());
```

Here's the code we're executing on DataAccessLayerB:

```
Database.SetInitializer(new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<ContextB, DALB.Migrations.Configuration>());
```

Both lines of code are being executed as I've stepped through the code and each is occurring in its own separate module(WPF app using PRISM).

Now, the only way the db migration for DataAccessLayerB works is if we explicitly use the DbMigrator class and call the Update() method. This will indeed migrate the db to latest although it creates the __MigrationHistory table outside of system tables in the db.

We are using entity framework 5.0 and we have AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false as we want to use code-based migrations for more granularity and control.

I could live with using the DbMigrator class for the second one but I really would like to understand why it does not work. I've seen the tutorials by Julie Lerman several times and read documentation online on code first migrations but still unable to find answer to this.

Any information as to what could be wrong would be greatly appreciated.